# Run shell command in Clojure from specific location

Tags: shell, clojure

I would like to read the output of a shell command. 
The shell command I want to read must be run from a specific location. (it's `git log`).

Is there a nice way to do this other than `cd`ing into the location, running `(clojure.java.shell/sh "git log")`, and then `cd`ing back to the working directory?

I'm looking for some sort of `(shell-at directory command)` function. A simple implementation of this function would also be appreciated. My experience with Clojure is minimal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`clojure.java.shell/sh` supports a `:dir` option to set the working directory of the sub-process:

```
(clojure.java.shell/sh "git" "log" :dir "/path/to/some/directory")
```

See [here](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.java.shell-api.html).